# Converting JavaScript object/map into nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, flot

I'm trying to use Flot.js to chart some data.
My JSON response contains this type of data mapping:

```
{123: 5, 534: 0, 724: 3}
```

I would like to convert that to:

```
[[123, 5], [534, 0], [724, 3]]
```

for use with Flot Charts. I also need to convert every element to a number instead of a String.

Is there an existing function to do this? Can't for the life of me find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = {123: 5, 534: 0, 724: 3};
var pairs = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return [Number(key), Number(obj[key])];
});

console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I think I was trying to do something similar from what I found online but I was keeping it inside a function which wasn't working.